# Is there an HTML forms builder that queries an Oracle schema for its initial functionality?

Tags: html, database, forms

Once upon a time, Oracle forms would query your database schema and create the initial set of forms based upon the structure of your tables.  If I remember correctly it would take into account the primary keys and foreign keys to make relationships between forms.  This was very handy to get started.  You could use the auto-generated forms to quickly jump into editing the detailed functionality that you needed.

Is there anything like this now but to produce HTML forms?  I have an existing schema which is relatively simple.  The previous version of the forms was in PHP and the developer has long since left.